# Calculate the integral $\int_{S_1(0)} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^8}$ where $S_1(0)$ is the Positively orientated circle of radius 1 centred at 0

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, analytic-functions

**editted in: it is a stipulation of the question to do this via expanding the sine function as a power series. deepest apologies for any confusion**

Can i get a workings check please; appreciate it.

$$\int_{S_1(0)} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^8}= \int_{S_1(0)}\frac{1}{z^{8}}\left[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right]$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{S_1(0)}\frac{1}{z^{8}}\left[\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right]$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{S_1(0)}\left[\frac{1}{z^{8}}\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right]$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{S_1(0)}\left[\frac{(-1)^{n}z^{2n-7}}{(2n+1)!}\right]$$
$$=\left\{\begin{matrix} 0 ~ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{3\}\\ -\frac{2 \pi i }{7!} ~ \text{for } n =3 \end{matrix}\right.$$

Via the cauchy integral theorem and deformation theorem.
Since $$\int_{S_{1}(0)}z^{n} = 0~\forall n \neq -1$$
and $2 \pi i$ otherwise

Since the co-effecient is also given by $$f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n!}{2 \pi i}\int_{S_{1}(0)} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw \implies$$
$$\frac{2 \pi i}{n!}f^{(n)}(0) = \int_{S_{1}(0)} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw$$
to make it crystal clear.
$$\frac{2 \pi i}{7!}\sin^{(7)}(0) = \oint_{S_{1}(0)} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^8}dz$$

$\sin$ repeats itself every fourth differentiation so we have $\sin(z) = \sin^{(4)}(z)$ and $-\cos(z) = \sin^{(3)}(z)$
which makes the final answer
$$\int_{S_1(0)} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^8}= -\frac{2 \pi i}{7!}$$

and so the results agree

now specific things to check for me if you please are the signs, i havent dropped an i or a -1 somewhere have i? and just the logic, i havent made any glaring mistakes have i?

Cheers

Comment: Try to solve this question with complex integration ,it will take only 3 to 4 steps

Comment: sorry, perhaps i should have put it as a stipulation that i'm required to do it by expanding the $sin(z)$ in power series, i'll add that now